# Paying before registration information is saved to the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have everything implemented with braintree and rails. However, I wanted to switch it up a little. I have a user role which is a business account. When someone wants to sign up as a business account I want them to pay before the devise registration is actually saved? I've seen it on a lot of website but cant really find any resources online how to do it. Someone please give an example of how it can work.

Comment: See [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) As-is, this question is unlikely to generate a response.

Answer (score 0):

As a general Idea what you can do is one registration of user on business account take the card information also for billing.

On submit of that information it will go to a controller action with all the params of registration and billing.

Try to charge the card through brain tree and if they payment is successfull you can register the user because you have access to the params and you can save this transaction for the user also.

Its just a general idea that how can you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments say, you question is vague.

What I would do is to have a column in that table that tells whether the record has payed or not.

If it hasn't payed then restrict its ability to log in. This way you can still record its information and it may be usefull for some cases, say to remind that user through an email that he/she should complete its payment.